# I need to know the ids of inserted,updated,deleted in Microsoft Sql Database 2012 with dates

Tags: sql-server-2012

I want to sync my local db with microsoft sql database so I need to know the ids of added records , updated and deleted records after last sync date, I mean I have the last sync date and I need to get all these ids after that date
is microsoft sql server store this information in logs or anywhere ?

Answer (score 0):

This isn't logged anywhere by default unless you either create a mechanism yourself to store the information or perhaps use Change Data Capture as documented here:

[Change Data Capture](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb522489%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

This allows SQL server to track data that changes in a table and then exposes the changes via functions that you can call to retrieve the data that has changed with each sync.